# Popup window not keeping width/height dimensions in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, popup

I'm using this script to open and center a popup window with a specific size. It works as intended, except in Safari version 9.0.1 on Mac OS 10.9.5 where the window opens in full size.
It works in all other browsers on Mac.

Any ideas why the specified window size doesn't work in Safari?

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
  var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
  var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
  var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
  var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
  var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
  var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
  var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

  // Puts focus on the newWindow
  if (window.focus) {
    newWindow.focus();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<a href="#" onclick="PopupCenter('http://www.google.com','Window title','500','600'); return false;">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation it seems that this issue only happens on this specific MacBook. It's not a generic issue, so I will close this topis for now.

Answer (score 0):

try using these for the width/height for this javascript supports all browsers:

```
var width = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

var heigth = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight;
```

It might be because this uses the body.clientHeight/body.clientWidth, not 100% sure though.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah that's a bummer, can't really help you further for I don't have a mac and safari doesn't really work on windows